# Android Studio python plugin fails to load

Tags: android, python, android-studio

Has anyone tried the python plugin for Android Studio?

When I attempted to open a py file in android studio it prompted me to install the "Python" plugin, so I did. After it installs and restarts the app, I go to Settings -> Plugins and the plugin is Red. If you check and uncheck it I get this error:

"Unable to apply changes: plugin "Python" won't be able to load"

Anyone know how to get the plugin to work? I'm running Android Studio on the Stable Channel, version 1.0.1.

The Python plugin version it tries to install is 3.4.135.24 from http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a plugin made for Jetbrain  Pycharm IDE, not for android studio, you need to check more details about it.

Comment: Ok, well android studio prompted me to install it, so I assumed the plugin would work with it. Why would it prompt me to install a plugin that is not compatible?

Comment: Still does not seem to work on 1.4 either :( Oh well.